# What points I should keep in mind while integrating google tag (GTM) in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

I would like to use Google tag manager in my chrome extension. What points should I keep in mind while integrating google tag (GTM) in chrome extension?

Comment: In my extension content script injects some html in the page and not sure where to put the GTM code that i grabbed from GTM dashboard. The documentation says the GTM code should be pasted right after the body tag starts. In my case there is no body tag. SO i m confused on this. Please note that I am new to GTM and using it for the first time.

Comment: all pages have a <body> thou

Comment: My extension creates some html based on the website and inject it into the website body. Do you mean that i should inject that GTM code into the website body?

Comment: never used gtm. but in trying to understand the issue. what have you tried that didnt work (but did work on a normal html page)

Comment: Ok ZIg, thanks for checking in. Let me look a deeper into the gtm. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since google chrome extension works in context of the current opened website. The content script is injected in to the DOM of current website and. Therefore we can not use the body tag of the website.

So I have to inject an iframe here. I have created a chrome extension page and used it as src of the injected iFrame. Now I have the dedicated html page with the body tag that I can use to put gtm code. But its not over yet. Since the chrome "content_security_policy" won't allow to execute inline javascript code the GTM code must be in a .js file.

gtm.js:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
```

One more change to do here is to prefix https: with //www.googletagmanager.com

Html code:

```
<body >
<script src="js/gtn.js"></script>
```

Please see this url for a quick installation guide.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?vid=1-635768734723363100-1900843843

Posting this answer so this may be may helpful for others.

Regards.